# When a group acts on a metric space isometrically, transitively, and faithfully, is it a closed subspace of the isometry group?

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, topological-groups

Suppose you have a group $G$ acting on $ (M,d)$ a compact metric space by isometries (meaning $d(gx,gy) = d(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in M$ and  all $g \in G$), transitively and faithfully.

You can define a metric on $G$ thinking about it as a topological subgroup of the isometries on $M$ ($\operatorname{Isom}(M)$) with the sup metric, being more specific, if you take $g,h \in G$, let the distance between them be $$ \rho (g,h) = \displaystyle\sup_{x \in M} d(gx,hx) .$$ I think it's true that $G$ is a closed subspace of $\operatorname{Isom}(M)$, is that true? How can I prove it?

Comment: @DanielRust : It's interesting that you mention this because all the examples I try to come up seem to face the same issue of only being *densely* transitive (i.e. that the orbits are dense but not closed).

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Sorry I probably shouldn't have deleted my comment. I deleted because I didn't see the transitive hypothesis in the question. For completion of the comments, I suggested the translation action on a flat torus along an irrational slope.

Comment: Patrick Da Silva asked for his deleted comment to be reposted: @DanielRust : This is not transitive, the orbit of an element is only dense.

Comment: Did I? Anyway it's good you did. :)

Comment: "Probably the subgroup of translations along a fixed irrational slope on the flat torus is not a closed subgroup of its isometry group." –  Daniel Rust"

Answer (score 1):

By the **closed map lemma** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_map), you can answer by the affirmative in the case where the group $G$ itself is compact. This is because metric spaces are always Hausdorff, so the inclusion map $i : G \to \mathrm{Isom}(M)$ is continuous, hence a closed map (by the closed map lemma ; note that it is not that hard to prove, you should give it a try). Since you were acting on a compact space $M$, this probably explains why you believe the result is true ; I had similar intuition, but all my examples involved a compact group $G$.

I couldn't solve the problem in full generality.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Actually I have proved that $Isom(M)$ is compact with this metric by a diagonal argument, what I'm trying to prove is that $G$ is compact, so it would be enough to show it's closed. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

This is already false for the sphere $S^3$ with the standard metric. The group G is isomorphic to $SU(2) \times R$.

Edit: Here is a simplified version of the above example, which assumes that you only know linear algebra (and general topology).

1. Verify that the unitary group $U(2)< GL(2, {\mathbb C})$ acts isometrically on ${\mathbb C}^2={\mathbb R}^4$ (equipped with the standard metric) and acts faithfully on the unit sphere $S^3\subset {\mathbb C}^2$. In particular, this action is isometric with respect to the restriction of the standard metric to $S^3$ (you can also use the induced Riemannian metric -  this does not matter).
2. Verify that the subgroup $SU(2)= U(2)\cap SL(2, {\mathbb C})$ acts transitively on $S^3$. Bonus: The action is also simply transitive.
3. Verify that the group of scalar unitary 2-by-2 matrices $Z(U(2))\cong S^1$ contains a subgroup $H$ isomorphic to the infinite cyclic group ${\mathbb Z}$. Bonus: $Z(U(2))$ is the center of $U(2)$.
4. Verify that $H$ is not closed in $S^1$. Bonus: $H$ is dense in $S^1$. If this is too hard, replace the infinite cyclic subgroup of $S^1$ with the subgroup of $S^1$ consisting of rotations by angles which are rational multiples of $\pi$.
5. Take the subgroup $G< U(2)$ generated by $H$ and $SU(2)$. This subgroup acts  faithfully, transitively and isometrically on $S^3$, but $G$ is not closed in the full isometry group of $S^3$. Bonus A: $G$ is isomorphic to $H\times SU(2)$ (provided that $H\cong {\mathbb Z}$ of course). Bonus B: The full isometry group of $S^3$ is the orthogonal group $O(4)$. Bonus C: The topology on $O(4)$, defined via the sup-metric, is the same as the matrix topology.

Comment: What group $G$? I don't even know what action you are talking about ; there is a group action in the OP's statement.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: The isometry group of $S^3$ is $O(4)$; its connected component of the identity is $SO(4)$, whose universal (2-fold) cover is $SU(2)\times SU(2)$; $G=SU(2)\times R$, where $R$ is a generic 1-parameter subgroup of $SU(2)$; it is noncompact and, hence, is not closed. Last thing you need to know is that $SU(2)$ acts transitively on $S^3$. Is it all clear now?

Comment: So essentially you found a compact space $M$ with isometry group isomorphic to $G \times H$ where $G$ acts transitively and you took a non-closed subgroup of $H$, say $K$, so that $G \times K$ is not closed in $G \times H$. This example involves quite a lot of computations... I don't wanna go through them! OP should tell us if he did.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Almost right, except that the product group $Spin(4)=SU(2)\times SU(2)$ does not act faithfully on the sphere (you divide it by $Z_2$ in order to get the faithful action: The quotient group is $SO(4)$). All this is quite standard. The exceptional isomorphism $Spin(4)\cong SU(2)\times SU(2)$ plays a prominent role in geometric topology, namely, SD and ASD connections on 4-dimensional vector bundles over 4-manifolds - Donaldson's theory.

Comment: studiosus:  Do you know whether it's true that, under the OPs hypothesis, $G$ necessarily contains a subgroup closed in $Iso(M)$ which still acts transitively?  All the counterexamples I know to the OPs original question have the form you gave:  two different compact Lie groups, one a subset of the other, both act transitively and faithfully.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: I do not know an example, but, on the other hand, I see no reason for it not to exist. I will think about it though.